# System.Net.HttpClient throws COMException when attempting to access internet from corporate domain

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, dotnet-httpclient, xamarin.uwp

I am writing my first UWP app (for Windows 10 only), using Xamarin.Forms.
I have written the following test class to establish that I can connect to the internet from my app:

```
public class NetworkInterface
{
    private static readonly System.Net.Http.HttpClient WebClient = new HttpClient();

    private void Get()
    {
        try
        {
            var response = WebClient.GetAsync($"https://google.com/foo").Result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect that I would receive a 404 response to this query, but instead I receive the following:

`System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the 
request. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The text 
associated with this error code could not be found.
A connection with the server could not be established`

I know this question has been posed a few times before, and that the answer is typically that the author has not enabled certain UWP Capabilities. I have attempted to remove that as a potential barrier by enabling all available Capabilities. From my Package.appxmanifest:

```
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
    <Capability Name="codeGeneration" />
    <Capability Name="allJoyn" />
    <uap:Capability Name="enterpriseAuthentication" />
    <uap4:Capability Name="userDataTasks" />
    <uap:Capability Name="voipCall" />
    <uap:Capability Name="videosLibrary" />
    <uap3:Capability Name="userNotificationListener" />
    <uap:Capability Name="userAccountInformation" />
    <iot:Capability Name="systemManagement" />
    <uap2:Capability Name="spatialPerception" />
    <uap:Capability Name="sharedUserCertificates" />
    <uap:Capability Name="removableStorage" />
    <uap3:Capability Name="remoteSystem" />
    <mobile:Capability Name="recordedCallsFolder" />
    <uap:Capability Name="picturesLibrary" />
    <uap2:Capability Name="phoneCallHistoryPublic" />
    <uap:Capability Name="phoneCall" />
    <uap4:Capability Name="offlineMapsManagement" />
    <uap:Capability Name="objects3D" />
    <uap:Capability Name="musicLibrary" />
    <iot:Capability Name="lowLevelDevices" />
    <uap:Capability Name="contacts" />
    <uap:Capability Name="chat" />
    <uap:Capability Name="blockedChatMessages" />
    <uap:Capability Name="appointments" />
    <uap3:Capability Name="backgroundMediaPlayback" />
    <uap6:Capability Name="graphicsCapture" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="webcam" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="proximity" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="pointOfService" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="microphone" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="location" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="gazeInput" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth" />
  </Capabilities>
```

However, it is my understanding that I should only need the "internetClient" Capability for my intended use of accessing APIs over the internet.

Here are some additional wrinkles:

1. I successfully receive a 404 when I disable my ethernet connection
   and connect to wifi. If I connect to VPN over wifi back into my
   domain I get the exception again.
2. Running the same query in Postman
   (even against the real API I'm trying to access) works regardless of
   network/domain connection.

My hunch is that UWP is lacking some sort of authorization or capability I don't know about for my domain network. Thanks for any advice on this!

Comment: Check if there is some proxy setting, which is common in domain network.

Comment: I don't see any proxy settings, and when I run the checknetisolation command line tool, it lists the correct IPs for the API, followed by a generic message that "The following resources had some other network error"

Comment: Our IT department explained to me that we do use a domain controller for ethernet and VPN, but I'm not sure what that means for me (I'm a networking novice). Here again, DNS does not seem to be the issue since the correct IPs show in the network logs.

Comment: Try to use privateNetworkClientServer  to support Homes and work networks.For more detail you can refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#general-use-capabilities

Comment: Thanks for the response, Lucas, however I already have that Capability enabled.

Comment: occopuyo - What was the solution for this? I am also facing the same.

Comment: @Tarak I don't remember what other solutions I tried to overcome this issue, but I do know I eventually scrapped the project and implemented the application in WPF :( I hope you find something!

Comment: I had to enable "Internet(Client & Server)" permission in the package manifest instead of "Internet (Client)".